# Searching a text file for something that is different every time

Tags: java, search, netbeans

I have a text file that I would like to find a date and time that will be different each and every time.

**e.g."StartTime": "2017-09-25 08:00:00"**

It will always begin with "StartTime" its just the date and time always changes.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions with capture groups.

Comment: Use a HashMap to store each new occurrence of your timestamp. If the next timestamp is already present in the HashMap, skip past it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to read a CSV file. Really the best way would be to use a CSV parsing library and then use the java time library to parse the text as a date & time object.

Having said that, if you want to do it manually then the solution is to use a regular expression with capture groups to search, for example `\"StartTime\":[ ]*\"([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\"`. You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/9FcdCu/1

See this page for info on regex, in particular the section on capture groups: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/